# How to use C# HTTPClient with Windows Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I wrote a console app that will read a text file of links and test them using the HttpClient class to check if the links exist.  It works wonderfully at home when tested against common links such as google.com.

When I run the app at under my work intranet, though, I get "Forbidden" errors when it checks links on our company Sharepoint and "Unauthorized" errors when it checks links on the Azure Website.  My hope was that running it under my authorized Windows desktop PC would be all I needed for it to work, but nope.

Any hints one how to pass my Network credentials when I access the links with HttpClient?

EDIT:  Added code to handle passed console argument (string of authentication cookies)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace linkbot
{
    class Program
    {   
        private static async Task ProcessRepositories(string the_url, string the_cookies)
        {   int the_index=the_url.IndexOf("/",9);
            string base_string=the_url;
            string the_rest="/";
            if (the_index>=0)
            {
                base_string=the_url.Substring(0,the_index);
                the_rest=the_url.Substring(the_index);
            }
            
            try {
                var baseAddress = new Uri(base_string);
                using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false })
                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
                {
                    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, the_rest);
                    message.Headers.Add("Cookie", the_cookies);
                    var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
                    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
                Write("\n" + the_url + " - WORKED!");
            }
            catch(Exception e )
            {
                Write("\nFailed: " + the_url + "||||||" +e.ToString() );
                //throw e;
            }
        }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length<2){
                Console.Write("\n###################\nLinkChecker by Sean J. Miller 2022\n\nusage:\n    linkchecker.exe <linkfile> <cookies>\nwhere <linkfile> contains a text file of fully specified links (URLs) with one link per line.  Example, https://www.google.com\n\nAn output file is generated titled brokenlinks.txt in the same directory where LinkChecker was launched.  <cookies> should be a string such as \"cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2;cookie3=value3;\"\n###################\n\n\n");
                return;
            }
            System.IO.File.Delete("brokenlinks.txt");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("brokenlinks.txt", "Last Check Started " + (DateTime.Now).ToString());
            int counter=0;
            int total_lines=TotalLines(@args[0]);
            Console.Write("Started " + (DateTime.Now).ToString() + "\n");
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@args[0]))
            {
                Console.Write("Processing Link " + (++counter) + "/" + total_lines + "\n");
                await ProcessRepositories(line, args[1]);
            }
            Console.Write("Finished " + (DateTime.Now).ToString() + "\n");
            Write("\n");
        }

        static void Write(string the_text)
        {
            //Console.Write(the_text);
            try   
            {  
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText("brokenlinks.txt", the_text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)   
            {  
                throw ex;  
            }
        }

        static int TotalLines(string filePath)
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (r.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have proxies / internet filters at work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set `UseDefaultCredentials` to true to use the current logged-on user credentials in your request. You can do that by instantiating your HttpClient like so:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply.  Unfortunately, it still resulted in the same failed connections and exceptions (Forbidden for SharePoint and Unauthorized for Azure).  I can reach the same sites with Microsoft Edge and Chrome from the same PC without any authentication prompts.

Comment: This could be because you are already signed in on those browsers. Can you do the same from Incognito mode?

Comment: Good point.  My company deactivates the ability to do incognito mode, so I clicked "sign out" on my profile.  When I tried one of the links, it took me to the sign on process first.  Does this mean that the only way to test the links would be through a signed in Browser - or would there be a way to login with code in dotnet?

Comment: @SeanMiller - Once you're signed in, there is like a cookie that gets stored by your browser that identifies you or your session. Use developer tools to see what cookies are set after you login, and then manually add those cookie values to your request.

Comment: Thanks.  In Edge, I was able to click the three dots-->More Tools-->Developer Tools-->Application-->Cookies.  I was glad to see the required cookies.  Now to figure out how to hard code them into my c# code.  Once I pull that off, I'll try to find a way to read the cookies if possible so they don't have to be hard coded.  I will update my code above if I pull it off.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnGlenn!  I updated my code in my original post to use the cookies.  It worked like a charm!

Comment: I'm glad it worked!!! You'll just have to update those cookies every once in a while. If you look at the POST request from when you logged in, you might even be able to write a function to send the authentication request to get those cookies depending on how the authentication works.

Comment: I was thinking one approach to grabbing the cookies would be parsing the cookies file in the Edge local directory.  I found the file, but it appears to be binary.  When I google for it, I just see posts over 10 years old that wouldn't apply to Edge.  Any thoughts on this?  (Side Note-I was able to inspect 1900 links in 10 minutes.  Thanks for that!)

Comment: Would it work if I Initialize my Static HttpClient with this handler , but later use the same httpClient with Bearer Authentication?